# How do I sort ScanResult from the WifiManager based on signal?

Tags: android, sorting, android-wifi, wifimanager

I was looking on stackoverflow on how to sort a list based on signal strength (referred to as `level` in the WifiManager library). I saw that you can use the function `Collection.sort()`. However, I am confused where I put the fact that I want to sort the list via `level`, where the highest number is at beginning and the lowest is at the bottom.

As you can see it returns a few things in each object:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html
I am not that advanced, but I know I can access the level by doing something like this

```
for (int i=0; i < scanList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(scanList.get(i).level); // Prints the level for each access point
}
```

---

```
WifiManager myWifiManager;
myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
myWifiManager.startScan();
List<ScanResult> scanList = myWifiManager.getScanResults();
Collections.sort(scanList);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass a [comparison logic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T)) to [Collection sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator));

```
class Signal_Strength_Comparator implements Comparator<ScanResult> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ScanResult scan0, ScanResult scan1) {
        return scan0.level-scan1.level;
    }
}
```

now pass this to Collection.sort:

```
WifiManager myWifiManager;
myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
myWifiManager.startScan();
List<ScanResult> scanList = myWifiManager.getScanResults();
Collections.sort(scanList,new Signal_Strength_Comparator());
```